# iOS/Swift: Image won't save into CoreData, app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, persistence

I'm trying to store image icons into `CoreData`, and I keep getting this error after the app crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "weatherIcon"; desired type = NSData; given type = Swift._NSContiguousString;

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let forecast = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Forecast", into: context)
forecast.setValue("\(forecastInfo)", forKey: "forecastDetails")

let iconData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(icon, 1.0)!) 
forecast.setValue("\(iconData)", forKey: "weatherIcon")
do {
    try context.save()
    print("Forecast saved")
}catch {
    print("Error saving data")   
}
```

'icon' is being grabbed from another ViewController, just like forecastInfo.

```
var forecastInfo = [String]()    
var icon = UIImage()
```

I understand what the error message says, but the value property is binary data and I've already converetd the image icon into Data before saving.
Everything is stored just fine, except the icon.
What am I missing?

Entity: **Forecast**

Attributes: **weatherIcon:** Binary Data, **forecastDetails**: String

Comment: forecast.setValue(iconData, forKey: "weatherIcon")

Comment: I never suppost to tel you that store image data in to coredata. you must manage the save image in to document directory and save the image name in to the coredata. its a master way to work with image and coredata

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you!!!

Comment: I read a little bit about saving images inro directories as you suggested, but I only have a few icons and figured and I could just convert them into Data and save them. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 1):

As Quoc Nguyen wrote you had a typo in your 6th code line:

It should be:

```
forecast.setValue(iconData, forKey: "weatherIcon")
```